# Why Can't we use an object with "Tell the truth" or "Tell a lie"?

Tags: grammaticality

I am learning "Reported Speech" and a rule says that "tell" has to be followed by an object, except with the expressions "tell the truth, tell a lie..."

Can't we say, "He told *me* the truth"?

Comment: "He told me the truth" is fine, as are other variations like "Tell us the truth".

Comment: "Tell the truth" *does* have an object. It has a direct object. The verb is "tell" and the direct object is "the truth." "Tell a lie" likewise *does* have an object. It has a direct object. The verb is "tell" and the direct object is "a lie." You can even add an indirect object to both of those, like "me," so you can say, "Tell *me* the truth," or, "Tell the truth to *me*," and, "Tell *me* a lie," or, "Tell a lie to *me*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be used like this. I guess the rule means in the following phrase, you can cross off the object instead of that an object is forbidden: tell a lie, tell the truth...
Tell me the truth: tell somebody something.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Tell me the truth* is an example of a common pattern in English with **ditransitive** verbs - those that take both a direct and an indirect object.

So

> Give the book to me.

and

> Give me the book.

are both fully grammatical, and precisely equivalent in meaning. "The book" is the direct object, and "me" the indirect.

Similarly

> Show John the letter = Show the letter to John.

This can even be done when the indirect object is a "benefactive", showing whose benefit something is done for:

> Peter baked Sally a cake = Peter baked a cake for Sally.

So, in this case

> He told me the truth = He told the truth to me.

*The truth* is the direct object, and *me* the indirect object.